# Can't remove large file from EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use EGit on Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) and can not completely
remove large file BillWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

(I've removed it already from source folder, but can't do it from local Git repository)
Also I can't have access to command line Git tool, I just can't find git.exe.

So, my output:

```
Repository https://github.com/nnn/nnn.git

pre-receive hook declined
error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
error: Trace: dde7f00c2fbfcbdf958d7869e8a8d0bb
error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
error: File BillWeb/src/main/java/WindowsService/BillWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is 117.23 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Comment: Just removing it from your current commit, will not remove it from earlier commits.  You may need to rewrite history manually or use one of the tools for doing this.

Comment: Your first priority will most likely get to being able to invoke git from the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git force push to github rejected for large file that is deleted and no longer tracked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446713/git-force-push-to-github-rejected-for-large-file-that-is-deleted-and-no-longer-t)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I installed git CMD to my Windows OS.
Then I used this command:

git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch BillWeb/src/main/java/WindowsService/BillWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

And it completely deleted this file from git history. Also I used double quotes instead single, I think it is because of OS requriments.

Thanks to  @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen